# Maximum value of $(1 − x)(2 − y)^ 2 (x + y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Additional Info

$x < 1, y<2, x+y>0$
I tried doing AM-GM (since all of the terms are positive.

$(1 − x)(2 − y)^ 2 (x + y) = (2-2x)(2-y)(2-y)(2x+2y)*1/4$
this way we can cancel the x and y's

thus the maximum value is

$((2-2x+2-y+2-y+2x+2y+1/4)/5)^5$

but the answer is said to be 1(?) where $x =0,$ and $y = 1$

Can someone tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Let $u=1-x,v=2-y.$ Then $u,v>0$ and $u+v<3.$ And the formula is $uv^2(3-u-v).$ That should simplify it somewhat.

Comment: don't i still have to  multiply it by 4 so it becomes (2u)(v)(v)(6-2u-2v) so that it cancels in the arithmetic part of the AM>GM inequality? isn't it essentially the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AM-GM the equality occurs for
$$2-2x=2-y=2x+2y=\frac{1}{4},$$ which is impossible.

I think, it's better to make the following.

By AM-GM
$$(1-x)(2-y)^2(x+y)=4(1-x)\left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2(x+y)\leq$$
$$\leq4\left(\frac{1-x+2\left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)+x+y}{4}\right)^4=\frac{81}{64}.$$
The equality occurs for $$1-x=1-\frac{y}{2}=x+y$$ or
$$(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right),$$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: why isnt the 4 included inside the $()^4$, its also present in the geometric mean right?

Comment: @SuperMage1 Because we want an equality occurring, but $4=1-x=1-\frac{y}{2}=x+y$ is impossible.  I added something. See now.

Comment: shouldn't the equation 5throot(4*(1-x)*(1-y/2)*(1-y/2)(x+y)) < (4+1+1+1+x+y-x-y)/5, why is the 4 not included in the 5throot?

Comment: @SuperMage1 See please my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

**A much more Logical way to solve this without algebraic manipulations:**

Since we want to maximize $(1-x)(2-y)^2(x+y)$ , and all the terms are positive, we can see that we might want to maximize $(2-y)^2$ in particular as it is the biggest among all terms.

$$\max \space(2-y)^2 = (2-0)^2 = 4 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space \text for \space y = 0$$

So the equation is reduced to $$(1-x)\times 4\times(x+0)$$
$$= 4\times(1-x)\times x$$
Again to $\max$ this equation further , we want to maximize $(1-x)\times x$ , which happens at $x=\frac 12.$

Hence $$\max \space[(1-x)(2-y)^2(x+y)] = \left(1-\frac12\right) \times (2-0)^2 \times \left(\frac12 + 0 \right)$$
$$ = \frac12\times4\times\frac12 = 1$$

Comment: Are you sure? I think we can get a greater value.

Comment: @ Michael Rozenberg Can you help me out with it ?

Comment: Just see my solution.

Comment: I meant in my answer

Comment: $(2-y)^2\leq4$ it's true. But $x+y\leq x$ is wrong. I think it's impossible to fix this mistake.